# How to add values in an empty numpy array?

Tags: python, list, numpy, matrix

I created an array using `numpy.empty()`. Now I want to add new values to that array based on the if-else condition. I wrote a for loop for that with the if-else condition inside. I only want to add values to the columns belonging to the first row. But after running the code I've written below, I'm getting some random values in the asr matrix instead of 1 and 0.

My code:

```
number_rows = 16
number_cols = 10
asr = np.empty((number_rows, number_cols))
 
for i in range(10): 
  if prediction[i] == check_keep[i]:
    asr[0][i] = 1 
  else:
    asr[0][i] = 0 
 
asr
```

I'd appreciate any help here.

Comment: Use `np.zeros` or `np.ones`, `np.empty` initialises with random numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.zeros` or `np.ones`, `np.empty` initialises with random numbers

```py
number_rows = 16
number_cols = 10
asr = np.zeros((number_rows, number_cols)) #np.zeros instead
 
for i in range(10): 
  if prediction[i] == check_keep[i]:
    asr.iloc[0, i] = 1 #also it is better to use np indexing here
  else:
    asr.iloc[0, i] = 0
```